# Splitting long piped chains in sub-chains without loosing information about parameters passes between sub-chains

Tags: rxjs

I have a long chain of operations within a pipe. Sub-parts of this chain represent some sort of high level operation. So, for instance, the code could look something like

```
firstObservable().pipe(

  // FIRST high level operation
  map(param_1_1 => doStuff_1_1(param_1_1)),
  concatMap(param_1_2 => doStuff_1_2(param_1_2)),
  concatMap(param_1_3 => doStuff_1_3(param_1_3)),

  // SECOND high level operation
  map(param_2_1 => doStuff_2_1(param_2_1)),
  concatMap(param_2_2 => doStuff_2_2(param_2_2)),
  concatMap(param_2_3 => doStuff_2_3(param_2_3)),
)
```

To improve readability of the code, I can refactor the example above as follows

```
firstObservable().pipe(
  performFirstOperation(),
  performSecondOperation(),
}

performFirstOperation() {
  return pipe(
      map(param_1_1 => doStuff_1_1(param_1_1)),
      concatMap(param_1_2 => doStuff_1_2(param_1_2)),
      concatMap(param_1_3 => doStuff_1_3(param_1_3)),
  )
}  

performSecondOperation() {
  return pipe(
      map(param_2_1 => doStuff_2_1(param_2_1)),
      concatMap(param_2_2 => doStuff_2_2(param_2_2)),
      concatMap(param_2_3 => doStuff_2_3(param_2_3)),
  )
}
```

Now, the whole thing works and I personally find the code in the second version more readable. What I loose though is the information that `performFirstOperation()` returns a parameter, `param_2_1`, which is then used by `performSecondOperation()`.

Is there any different strategy to break a long pipe chain without actually loosing the information of the parameters passed from sub-pipe to *sub-pipe*?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your usage of `forkJoin` here, forkJoin generates an observable, it's not an operator.

Comment: The operators I use in the example are just "an example" of what can happen. As far as `forkJoin` is concerned, you are right, it is not right to have it there. Thanks for the feedback, I have edited my question and made simpler.

Comment: gotcha, didn't end up mattering much to the final answer, as the real dependency here is just building your secondary pipeline as an inner observable of the first pipeline to preserve the outter observable data.

Comment: In what way do you want to show that a return value is passed from `performFirstOperation()` to `performSecondOperation()`? All pipable operator functions take an Observable as input and return an Observable. So when you're chaining operators it'll always be the case that the Observable returned from one operator is used as input for the next one. Using `typescript` would give you a little for flexibility as to show what input one operator expects and what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

setting aside the improper usage of forkJoin here, if you want to preserve that data, you should set things up a little differently:

```
firstObservable().pipe(
  map(param_1_1 => doStuff_1_1(param_1_1)),
  swtichMap(param_1_2 => doStuff_1_2(param_1_2)),
  // forkJoin(param_1_3 => doStuff_1_3(param_1_3)), this isn't an operator
  concatMap(param_2_1 => {
    const param_2_2 = doStuff_2_1(param_2_1); // run this sync operation inside
    return doStuff_2_2(param_2_2).pipe(
      concatMap(param_2_3 => doStuff_2_3(param_2_3)),
      map(param_2_4 => ([param_2_1, param_2_4])) // add inner map to gather data
    );
  })
)
```

this way you've built your second pipeline inside of your higher order operator, so that you can preserve the data from the first set of operations, and gather it with an inner map once the second set of operations has concluded.

for readability concerns, you could do something like what you had:

```
firstObservable().pipe(
  performFirstOperation(),
  performSecondOperation(),
}

performFirstOperation() {
  return pipe(
    map(param_1_1 => doStuff_1_1(param_1_1)),
    swtichMap(param_1_2 => doStuff_1_2(param_1_2)),
    // forkJoin(param_1_3 => doStuff_1_3(param_1_3)), this isn't an operator
  )
}  

performSecondOperation() {
  return pipe(
    concatMap(param_2_1 => {
      const param_2_2 = doStuff_2_1(param_2_1);
      return doStuff_2_2(param_2_2).pipe(
        concatMap(param_2_3 => doStuff_2_3(param_2_3)),
        map(param_2_4 => ([param_2_1, param_2_4]))
      );
    })
  )
}
```

an alternative solution would involve multiple subscribers:

```
const pipe1$ = firstObservable().pipe(
  performFirstOperation(),
  share() // don't repeat this part for all subscribers
);

const pipe2$ = pipe1$.pipe(performSecondOperation());
```

then you could subscribe to each pipeline independently.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my whole point is about splitting the long chain within the main pipe into smaller sub-pipes without loosing the information about parameters passed from one sub-pipe to the following

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I answered. I showed you the pattern for achieving this. It is to make your second pipe an inner observable of the first pipe as to preserve both inner and outer outcomes. The only other way to achieve this would be with multiple subscribers at different points in the pipeline.

Comment: added an edit to show what the multiple subscriber set up would be

Comment: Thanks again, but let me try to make my point ore clear. If I look at the content of the main pipe, i.e. `performFirstOperation(),
  performSecondOperation(),` it does not appear that `performFirstOperation()` is passing the parameter `param_2_1`, whatever that is, to `performSecondOperation()`. So my question is whether there is a technique which allows to show this parameter passing more clearly, while ensuring a split into sub pipes.

Comment: I think I get it now, I'd have to say that I don't think so, nor do I think it should be needed. It's just kind of how observable pipelines work that the output of the prior link in the chain is the input to the next link.  I see what you're saying though, and truth be told, I don't usually break up my operations like this unless I plan on having a highly reusable set of operations, which happens kind of rarely and are usually more in the form of generic custom operators that wouldn't look like you have.  I don't know if I've ever subdivided a stream for readability purposes

Answer (score 0):

I broke one complex operation into two like this:

**Main Code**

```
  dataForUser$ = this.userSelectedAction$
    .pipe(
      // Handle the case of no selection
      filter(userName => Boolean(userName)),
      // Get the user given the user name
      switchMap(userName =>
        this.performFirstOperation(userName)
          .pipe(
            switchMap(user => this.performSecondOperation(user))
          ))
    );
```

**First Operation**

```
  // Maps the data to the desired format
  performFirstOperation(userName: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.userUrl}?username=${userName}`)
      .pipe(
        // The query returns an array of users, we only want the first one
        map(users => users[0])
      );
  }
```

**Second Operation**

```
  // Merges with the other two streams
  performSecondOperation(user: User) {
    return forkJoin([
      this.http.get<ToDo[]>(`${this.todoUrl}?userId=${user.id}`),
      this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this.postUrl}?userId=${user.id}`)
    ])
      .pipe(
        // Map the data into the desired format for display
        map(([todos, posts]) => ({
          name: user.name,
          todos: todos,
          posts: posts
        }) as UserData)
      );
  }
```

Notice that I used another operator (`switchMap` in this case), to pass the value from one operator method to another.

I have a blitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-passdata-deborahk